# CSP Violation - Blocked URI is mentioned as "properties"

Tags: content-security-policy

We have implemented CSP policy in report-only mode and as part of violations received we have got a violation in "connect-src" directive where the blocked URI is mentioned as "properties".

It is difficult to identify what needs to be whitelisted and what is getting blocked. Mentioning the JSON below for reference.

**Note:** Violations were specific to Android Chrome Browser

JSON:

```
{
    csp-report": 
   {
      "document-uri": "https://*************",
      "effective-directive": "connect-src",
      "original-policy": "*policy*",
      "blocked-uri": "properties",
      "line-number": 2,
      "column-number": 535042,
      "source-file": "https://**************",
     "status-code": 200
  }
}
```

Just wanted to understand why this violation is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Usually such violations related to browser specific functions or browser extensions. So, this is not real URI blocked but something that browser tried to do.
In most cases such violations can be ignored until you get exact complains from users.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this that can be referred or any way to whitelist this in CSP?